# How to set boundaries of the scene in sprite kit with swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How do i keep nodes from leaving a scene. Before with objective c i used:

```
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.size];
```

How is this done in swift?

Comment: Hint: type `SKPhysicsBody(` and look at the autocomplete options. You could also check the [SKPhysicsBody class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/)

Answer (score 0):

Like so

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
```

Note that the `bodyWith...` Objective C methods on SKPhysicsBody has been replaced with `init` methods in Swift. As Ben suggests, have a look at the documentation for [SKPhysicsBody](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:)

One thing though. This method takes a `CGRect` and in your your example you are passing a `CGSize`, I don't know if that was a typo?

Comment: **Swift 4.0** self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)